# Fetch n bind data from StoredProcedure with Join, LINQ then Split. using IMultipleResults,Linq2SQL

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-sql, stored-procedures

I have an application in which I am using a stored procedure and LINQ.
My procedure looks like this:

```
myProc

select col1, Col2, Col3 from Tab1 inner join Tab2 on col1=ColA  join tab3 on Col1=ColD

Select cola, Colb, Colc from Taba inner join Tabb on cola=ColX  join tabc on Cola=ColY

Select colP, ColQ, ColR from TabP inner join TabQ on colP=ColW  join tabR on ColP=ColZ
```

I am executing this stored procedure in LINQ.
When I execute it I am getting the results in IMultipleResults.

Below is my code in LINQ:

```
[Function(Name = "dbo.MyProc")]
[ResultType(typeof(TabA))]
[ResultType(typeof(TabB))] .....
public IMultipleResults GetMultipleResults([Parameter(DbType = "VarChar(50)")] string i_Cola)
{
    IExecuteResult result = this.ExecuteMethodCall(this, ((MethodInfo)(MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod())), i_Cola);
    return (IMultipleResults)result.ReturnValue;
}
```

When I execute it as follows:

```
MyContext mCtx = new MyContext()
var allResult = mCtx.GetMultipleResults(txtName.Text.Trim());
IEnumerable<Taba> TabaRes = allResult.GetResult<Taba>();
IEnumerable<TabB> TabbRes = allResult.GetResult<Tabb>();
```

I am getting the column values of tables but I want the Inner Joined columns also.
I've referred to many blogs and forums, such as...

1. [Ben Hall's Blog](https://web.archive.org/web/20120213223823/http://blog2.benhall.me.uk:80/labels/Linq.html)
2. [Guy Burstein's Blog](https://web.archive.org/web/20131023015142/http://blogs.microsoft.co.il:80/blogs/bursteg/archive/2007/10/05/linq-to-sql-stored-procedures-with-multiple-results-imultipleresults.aspx)
3. [Microsoft's Blog](https://web.archive.org/web/20160227001739/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/swiss_dpe_team/archive/2008/02/04/linq-to-sql-returning-multiple-result-sets.aspx)

... to try to find a solution to my problem, but couldn't find any.

Answer (score 2):

well better to use views in respect to SP(If u are not able to write a linq to sql query),if u are using Linq to Sql its worthLess to use Sp becoze it decrease the performance.and one more thing if u are using Linq to sql there is no Need to use any type of join if ur data base is completely normalized.
If still ur prob is not solved just show me the table structure and what the out u need i will write a query for u...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this would be a stupid question, but in your store procedure:

```
select col1, Col2, Col3 from Tab1
inner join Tab2 on col1=ColA  join
tab3 on Col1=ColD
```

`col1,col2,col3` are all from `tab1`, but you never did a `select` from the other tables that you are trying to do `inner join`. Did you tried

```
select col1,col2,col3,colA,colB...
```

-or-

```
select * from...
```

Comment: Are you mad .......... I asked for solution in linq which ll solve my problem  not asked for a query

Comment: No need to be so nervous and offensive about it! Maybe I did not understand you. Could you elaborate. Would you like your store procedure to be rewritten in LINQ or ....? Please do explain.

Comment: @Umakanta its very bad form to be rude to people who are trying to help you.  Besides, your question wasn't exactly clear and could confuse a reasonable person.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand your need, but can you change the proc to return * or all the columns in all the tables you need?

Comment: NO I It ll decrease my Performance and there is joins and so I need some particular columns to return

Comment: So name all of the columns that you need returned, that what I meant by "or all the columns in all the tables you need"

Comment: This won't slow your performance, it surely would slow the performance, if you needed another query.

Answer (score 0):

If the stored procedure isn't returning the data required then the only option for LINQ would be for it to go query the database again itself.

This would mostly negate the point of having a stored procedure and be slower than just adding the required parameters to your stored procedure.